# Include escape sequence in a string sequence in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I am trying to send data to a thermal printer directly.

I have the following test data:

```
raw_data = bytes ("This is a test", "utf-8")
```

I would like to include two initial bytes to build the sequence ESC+@ (character ESC is ASCII 27) to initialize the printer.

How shall I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\033` to represent the `ESC` character.

```
raw_data = bytes ("\033@This is a test", "utf-8")
```

Comment: Since when is `\e` escape? When I try this, I just get two bytes: `\ ` and `e`. Do I need a newer Python or something?

Comment: Oops, it's `\e` in lots of other languages, but not Python. You have to use octal or hex code.